# p:datatable paging all entries elastic search index

Tags: elasticsearch, primefaces

I want to use a pageable primfaces datatable to display all entries in an elastic seach index.
Unfortunately the following code only returns 10 entries.

```
public ArrayList<Video> getAllVideos(String indexName) throws IOException{
    makeConnection();
    SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest(indexName);
    Scroll scroll = new Scroll(TimeValue.timeValueMinutes(1L));
    searchRequest.scroll(scroll);
    SearchSourceBuilder sourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
    sourceBuilder.query(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery());
    searchRequest.source(sourceBuilder);

    SearchResponse searchResponse = restHighLevelClient.search(searchRequest);
    return buildResponse(searchResponse, restHighLevelClient);
}
```

Does anybody have a working example for getting all records? Thanks

Comment: How is this PrimeFaces related?

Comment: Or do you perhaps mean you only get 10 entries in the datatable? If so, you need to also show us how you are using the `p:datatable` component. If I remember correctly, the default page size is 10 rows when you enable pagination in a PrimeFaces data table.